# Can't Read Data of Notification Message - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I used postman for Creating a Notification.Also I used Firebase Cloud Messaging as backend.
All works, even Notification pops in the android. But I can't read the data in my **debug console** ,

the Following errors are shown in console:

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(23051): broadcast received for message
W/FLTFireMsgService(23051): A background message could not be handled in Dart as no onBackgroundMessage handler has been registered.
W/FirebaseMessaging(23051): Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in AndroidManifest. Default value will be used.
```

**The Codes of the Push Notification class:**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cholachol_drive/globalvariables.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

class PushNotificationService {
  // final FirebaseMessaging fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future initialize(context) async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
      (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        // retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
        print("onMessage: $message");

        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          String rideID = message["data"]['ride_id'];
          if (rideID != null) {
            print("Fucked");
          } else {
            print('ride_id: $rideID');
          }
        }
      };
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
      (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        // retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          String rideID = message["data"]['ride_id'];
          if (rideID != null) {
            print("Fucked");
          } else {
            print('ride_id: $rideID');
          }
        }
      };
    });
  }

  Future<String> getToken() async {
    String token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    print("token: $token");

    DatabaseReference tokerRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref()
        .child("drivers/${currentFirebaseUser.uid}/token");

    FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('alldrivers');
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('allusers');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please identify at which line you are getting this error

Comment: it is a logic error

Comment: @AamirMZobayer I'm facing the same issue with my app. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have [`onBackgroundMessage`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#background_messages) implemented in your app. You need to use `onBackgroundMessage` in order to handle background messages. `onMessage` will only handle foreground messages.